# Need help with creating PDF from HTML using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm trying to crate a PDF out of a HTML page. The CMS I'm using is EPiServer.

This is my code so far:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        naaflib.pdfDocument(CurrentPage);
    }


    public static void pdfDocument(PageData pd)
    {
        //Extract data from Page (pd).
        string intro = pd["MainIntro"].ToString(); // Attribute
        string mainBody = pd["MainBody"].ToString(); // Attribute

        // makae ready HttpContext
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        // Create PDF document
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
        //PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);  

        pdfDocument.Open();
        pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph(pd.PageName));
        pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph(intro));
        pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph(mainBody));
        pdfDocument.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

This outputs the content of the article name, intro-text and main body.
But it does not pars HTML which is in the article text and there is no layout.

I've tried having a look at http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html without becomming any wiser.

Any pointers to the right direction is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For later versions of iTextSharp:**

Using iTextSharp you can use the `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList()` method to create a PDF from HTML.

`ParseToList()` takes a `TextReader` (an abstract class) for its HTML source, which means you can use a `StringReader` or `StreamReader` (both of which use TextReader as a base type).  I used a `StringReader` and was able to generate PDFs from simple mark up.  I tried to use the HTML returned from a webpage and got errors on all but the simplist pages.  Even the simplist webpage I retrieved (http://black.ea.com/) was rendering the content of the page's 'head' tag onto the PDF, so I think the `HTMLWorker.ParseToList()` method is picky about the formatting of the HTML it parses.

Anyway, if you want to try here's the test code I used:

```
// Download content from a very, very simple "Hello World" web page.
string download = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://black.ea.com/");

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
try {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("TestOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(download)) {
            ArrayList parsedList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null);
            document.Open();
            foreach (object item in parsedList) {
                document.Add((IElement)item);
            }
            document.Close();
        }
    }

} catch (Exception exc) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation on which HTML constructs `HTMLWorker.ParseToList()` supports; if you do please post it here.  I'm sure a lot of people would be interested.

**For older versions of iTextSharp:**
You can use the `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser.Parse` method to create a PDF based on html.

Here's a snippet demonstrating this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65); 
try  {
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("TestOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
      HtmlParser.Parse(document, "YourHtmlDocument.html");
   }
} catch(Exception exc)  { 
   Console.Error.WriteLine(exc.Message); 
}
```

The one (major for me) problem is the HTML must be strictly XHTML compliant.

Good luck!

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can `YourHtmlDocument.html` be the URL to the page?

Comment: PS. I don't think the newest version of iTextSharp has HtmlParser. The closest I get it `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker` But using that, requires a TextReader for the parsing.....

Comment: @Steven - You're right!  Sorry about that, I loaded up an old test program (with an old version of iTextSharp) when I answered your question.  You're right though, HTMLWorker is the way you'd want to do.  I edited my response based on (limited) testing I did with HTMLWorker and iTextSharp 5.0.

Comment: Great job Jay! If I remember correctly, I think the web pages must be using XHTML strict, or be 100% correct XHTML. So maybe that's why it's so picky! I will give it a go. If it prooves not to be good enough, I will use `ABCpdf`.