# iTextSharp: Writing RTF in a PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, rtf

I'm using iTextSharp (with C# and VS2008) to generate a report from a database table row. Generate PDF is not a problem... but when I try to add RTF text into the PDF I cant't find a way into iTextSharp object structure.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider converting your RTF to HTML and then writing your HTML to PDF using iTextSharp.

I've never done this but here are some resources that might help:
[Writing Your Own RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx)
[Need help with creating PDF from HTML using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593116/need-help-with-creating-pdf-from-html-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Thanks!

But it's possible to add RTF text in PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `iTextSharp.text.rtf.parser.RtfParser`

Answer (score 0):

Try using HtmlToPdfBuilder class at [www.hugoware.net](http://hugoware.net/blog/itextsharp-utility) from Hugo Bonacci. It shall convert HTML to PDF with external stylesheet as well.