# c# Stringbuilder: persisting a StringBuilder object into a varchar column - SQL Server

Tags: c#, itext

I have block of text read from a PDF document, using the ItextSharp library(method: GetResultantText())

Consider the text is outlined/formatted in paragraphs:

*"Paragraph One.

Paragraph Two.
...

Paragraph n
"*

Is there a way to use the C# StringBuilder object, or perhaps an alternate approach, to store the text while retaining the fomatting?: contains carriage returns and paragraphs etc. and store the value in a **varchar** field in SQL Server 08.

Ultimately I intend storing the text into a varchar field and would like to retain the line feeds, carriage return [basic fomatting metadata], otherwise the extracted text is a single block of text that isn't readabe when rendered.

I reckon invoking the toString() method on a StringBulder object removes all intermediate formatting characters in a text excecpt the terminating [newlinecharacter].

```
SimpleTextExtractionStrategy strategy;
            //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\pdfOutput.txt");

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                    buffer.AppendLine(strategy.GetResultantText());
                    //writer.WriteLine(strategy.GetResultantText());
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) { }
            }

            pdfText = buffer.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("* End: Text Extraction Process ...");
            return pdfText = buffer.ToString();
```

If I uncomment and output to a text file, the fomatting is retained.
However if I save the resulting text into and entity defined as: All i get is a single block of text:

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "ReportsText")]
    public class ReportsText
    {
        [Column (IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)] 
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public String image { get; set; } 

        [Column] public String announcement { get; set; }
    }
```

So pdfText is inteded to be stored into the annouuncement field. Cheers.

Comment: I don't think the formatting goes away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that it should remove formatting and if it doing so Make use of "`\r\n`" after each paragraph and than store it.

Comment: It turns out the formatting "\r\n" is indeed retained verified by fetching the value from the table and invoking Console.writeline(). Initially I was copying the value directoy from SQL Server Management studio and pasting into text file - which isn't the right way to verify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that using `StringBuilder` in itself will remove formatting, and will retain only new line characters. If you really want to store a string with formatting information into the database, I would suggest storing it as a pre-defined format--like XML, [RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823544/itextsharp-writing-rtf-in-a-pdf-document) or even [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593116/need-help-with-creating-pdf-from-html-using-itextsharp), then retrieve it the same way in order to be fed to iTextSharp.

Another way I can think of is to generate the PDFs directly then store the binary stream into the database as `nText` or clob. This is not the best practice though.