# HTML to PDF Solution (Handling Content, Headers and Footers)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to create a "report" by generating a PDF based on HTML.

At first, I simply attempted to write raw encoded HTML to a document and then print that document using Javascript. However, this gave me little to no control involving headers and footers.

I attempted using `thead` and `tfoot` elements, which worked reasonably well in most browsers, however I wasn't able to get the formatting that I was looking for.

Currently - I am trying to work on a server-side solution using iTextSharp in MVC3, however I am a bit lost as to how to proceed, having not worked with iTextSharp much.

**Input and Description of Output:**

There will be 4 items used in creating the Report:

- **Report Content** *(which is currently encoded HTML, as I am unsure if decoding will change any formatting)*
- **Report Title** *(will simply be the name of the PDF generated)*
- **Report Header** *(will be displayed at the upper-left of each page)*
- **Report Footer** *(will be displayed at the lower-left of each page)*

**Controller Action:**

```
//This will be accessed by a jQuery Post
[HttpPost]
public FileStreamResult GeneratePDF(string id)
{
      //Grab Report Item
      ReportClass report = reportingAgent.GetReportById(id);

      Document doc = new Document();

      //Do I need to decode the HTML or is it possible to use the encoded HTML?

      //Adding Headers / Footers

      //Best method of returning the PDF?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTextSharp cannot convert HTML to PDF. It's not what it was designed to do. It was designed to create PDF files from scratch, not converting between various formats into PDF. If you want to convert HTML into PDF you could for example use the the [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) library which is based on `iText`. I have [blogged](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/76-how-to-convert-xhtml-to-pdf-in-c.html) about how this could be done in .NET using [IKVM.NET Bytecode Compiler (ikvmc.exe)](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html).

So your controller action might look something along the lines of:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileStreamResult GeneratePDF(string id)
{
    ReportClass report = reportingAgent.GetReportById(id);
    return PdfResult(report.Html);
}
```

where `PdfResult` could be a custom action result taking the raw HTML and outputting the PDF into the response stream:

```
public class PdfResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly string _html;
    public PdfResult(string html)
    {
        _html = html;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        var builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        using (var bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_html)))
        using (var bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            var doc = builder.parse(bais);
            var renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(bao);
            var buffer = bao.toByteArray();
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin - I'll look into flying-saucer. It's always nicer to find the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Rionmonster, it's just one tool that I have successfully used in production applications. There might be other alternatives as well including commercial components.

Comment: Do you have any tools you would recommend for porting the flying-saucer library to .NET (as mentioned in your blog)

Comment: @Rionmonster, I have used the `ikvmc.exe` compiler which converts a .jar into .NET assembly.

Comment: Sorry about that - I JUST was about to delete that comment. It's one of those mornings. I appreciate it again.

Comment: I noticed that in the flying-saucer download, I was unable to find the core-renderer.jar file within it. Do I perhaps need the PDFRenderer.jar instead? (During the conversion - it threw several warnings as well, is that to be expected?)

Comment: @Rionmonster, ah maybe they changed it in the most recent version. It was a long time ago when I wrote this post and with an older version. As far as the errors during the conversion are concerned, I think they are more of a warning that you can ignore.

Comment: @Rionmonster, when I download flyingsaucer-R8.zip from here http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/downloads/list I get core-renderer.jar inside.

Comment: Thanks again Darin - I appeared to download the source rather than the binary.

Comment: Everything appears to work fine. The only issue deals with the DocumentBuilderFactory(), as it appears to be an interface, so I cannot create an instance of it. That's the only error that I am running into

Comment: @Rionmonster, I have updated my code to reflect this change that was introduced in the API since the time I wrote the blog post.

Comment: That fixed the issue. I just attempted to use it on with an example string containing "<strong>Test</strong>" but received a markup following the root element must be well formed error. Am I missing something, perhaps in the HTML?

Comment: @Rionmonster, flying-saucer expects a valid XHTML as input, including `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a better solution, but iTextSharp **can** parse HTML to PDF. The supported tags are far from complete but basic things like tables and fonts are for the most part good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593116/need-help-with-creating-pdf-from-html-using-itextsharp